# don't let Flex view resize after some screen size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using flutter web to create my new site. I am using Flexible widget but do not let it work after some browser dimension. i.e. after some browser dimension, this Flex view stopped working. How to do it?

Below is my homepage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.20,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(IconData(58819, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'), color: Colors.red), // apps icon
                    Text("mysite", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 7,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.20,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text("Word to PDF"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
      ],
      )      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LayoutBuilder` to calculate height after applying flex values. If resulting height will satisfy constraints - you continue to use flex. If it does not - use `SizedBox` instead.

Here is an example:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        final minHeight = 150.0;

        // 1 is flex value of the widget
        // 6 is sum of all flex values in column
        final flexHeight = 1 / 6 * constraints.maxHeight;
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(color: Colors.red),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(color: Colors.green),
            ),
            if (flexHeight > minHeight)
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: getConstrainedContainer(),
              ),
            if (flexHeight <= minHeight)
              SizedBox(
                height: minHeight,
                child: getConstrainedContainer(),
              )
          ],
        );
      }),
    ),
  ));
}

Widget getConstrainedContainer() {
  return Container(color: Colors.blue);
}
```

Note: provided example code requires dart 2.2.2 or higher